# Can I fill a hole with concrete that is close or even touches the footing of my house?

Tags: concrete, fence, post, footings

I am trying to put a wood post inside a hole filled with concrete. The hole is really close to my house footing (less than 2 inches), and I have a question:

Is it okay for the concrete in the hole to be so close (or even touching) the concrete of the footing of the house? The diameter of the hole should be bigger, and I'm considering just attaching it to the footing of the house.

The hole it is so close, that as I dig, I see the screws/bolts (I don't know how these are called) coming from the footing of the house.

Attached a couple of pictures to help understand the situation.

[image: Hole + Footing]
[image: Bolt coming from footing of the house]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no problem with filling the hole right next to the foundation. That exactly what they do when adding on additions to houses. The "bolts" you see coming out of the existing foundation are just nails used to frame the foundation/slab for pouring. You can cut those pieces off if you want, it won't affect the foundation.

Comment: That just looks like a form nail and could be removed or left.  rebar is generally 2" away from the surface of concrete if done correctly.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger  Zooming in on a larger screen, I think you're right. It does look like there's a head on it which eliminates mesh. Edited answer.